Cocoa: Native fullscreen transition and modal dialog on MacOS not working
The documentation around Cocoa is lacking when it comes to Native fullscreen support. I'm trying to find out if Cocoa supports toggling a window into fullscreen while simultaneously opening a modal dialog.
This seems to trigger the application to leave fullscreen instantly as if it's some kind of safety mechanism (or bug). Does anybody if this is the case?
Below follows the sample application that creates this behavior, but I've seen similar behavior in real world applications, which led me to write this sample application to ask if anybody has any clues.
The sample application has a button (two buttons really, but 1 is only interesting), that toggles the fullscreen and simultaneously opens a modal save-as dialog. This creates this described behavior.


#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (strong) NSWindow *window;
@property (strong) NSButton *fullscreenButton;
@property (strong) NSButton *saveOnlyButton;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Create the window
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
    self.window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                               styleMask:(NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable)
                                                 backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                   defer:NO];
    [self.window setTitle:@"Fullscreen & Save Panel"];
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    
    // Create the fullscreen and save button
    self.fullscreenButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200, 180, 200, 50)];
    [self.fullscreenButton setTitle:@"Go Fullscreen & Save"];
    [self.fullscreenButton setTarget:self];
    [self.fullscreenButton setAction:@selector(fullscreenButtonClicked:)];
    [[self.window contentView] addSubview:self.fullscreenButton];
    
    // Create the save only button
    self.saveOnlyButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200, 100, 200, 50)];
    [self.saveOnlyButton setTitle:@"Open Save Panel"];
    [self.saveOnlyButton setTarget:self];
    [self.saveOnlyButton setAction:@selector(saveOnlyButtonClicked:)];
    [[self.window contentView] addSubview:self.saveOnlyButton];
    
    [self.window center];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (void)fullscreenButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    // Go fullscreen
    [self.window toggleFullScreen:nil];
    
    // Open "Save As" panel (modal)
    [self openSavePanel];
}

- (void)saveOnlyButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    // Open "Save As" panel (modal)
    [self openSavePanel];
}

- (void)openSavePanel {
    // Open "Save As" panel in modal mode
    NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    [savePanel setTitle:@"Save As"];
    [savePanel setMessage:@"Choose a location to save the file."];
    [savePanel setAllowedFileTypes:@[@"txt", @"pdf"]];
    
    // Make the save panel modal
    NSInteger result = [savePanel runModal];  // This will make the panel modal
    
    if (result == NSModalResponseOK) {
        NSURL *selectedFileURL = [savePanel URL];
        // Handle the file URL here if necessary
        NSLog(@"File will be saved at: %@", selectedFileURL.path);
    }
}

@end


Apparently the transition to full screen fails if you run a modal save panel at the same time. Why do you want to do this?
